# Conditional generic type of function is being broke up into fragments of types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, conditional-types

I am trying to compose a generic conditional type. My try is:

```
type Some<T> = T extends (...args: any[]) => any ? (p: T) => T : T | ((p: T) => T);
```

When I create variable of this type

```
let v: Some<(() => void) | string | boolean>;
```

the type of it turns out to be

```
string | boolean | ((p: string) => string) | ((p: false) => false) | ((p: true) => true) | ((p: () => void) => () => void)
```

where even `boolean` type has been broke into `true` and `false` types behaving separately. What type I actualy want to build is

```
string | boolean | ((p: string | boolean | (() => void)) => string | boolean | (() => void))
```

How should I be to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because conditional types are [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). I'm not sure is't possible to get the type you want this way. But, you can describe the type in a different way, like:

```js
type Some<T> = Exclude<T, Function> | ((p: T) => T);
```

At least the produced type looks like the type you are expected. [Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBMAWBTYBrAyiAtomBeGAPACoB8AFBFogFwwCiAHsADYCuAJosQDQwBirMMCgBLcCRgAfGGTIAHWkQCUeCcpW4JlbAG4AUM0SwAbnjhJUGbAWgAnEWADmUmACMQIQwEMwL2RoljEBF2JXIAcihEaHClHSA).

Comment: Note that you can use the built-in utility type `Exclude<T, U>` instead of defining `Diff`.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the remark! I've updated the answer

Comment: I caught your point. And thank you. There is a flaw in your solution. You hardcoded the use case `() => void`. It perfectly works for `T = (() => void) | string | boolean`. The result is
`string | boolean | ((p: string | boolean | (() => void)) => string | boolean | (() => void))`
But for `(() => number) | string | boolean` it  is wrong:
`string | boolean | ((p: string | boolean | (() => void)) => string | boolean | (() => number))`
and should be
`string | boolean | ((p: string | boolean | (() => number)) => string | boolean | (() => number))`

Comment: The actual solution is in reducing the complexity of your proposition: `Exclude<T, Function> | ((p: T) => T)`

Comment: @AndreiKovalev may be, I just tried to create a type that matches the type from the question :) but it's hard to came up with a right solution without understanding the problem context. I've also started from the type you came to, but it doesn't match, so I complicated it a little :)

Comment: @ValeriyKatkov You better fix it so that I could upvote you answer.

Comment: @ValeriyKatkov I mean it matches